# how to deactivate fetch value database to select box in laravel 4

Tags: html, mysql, laravel-4

Iam trying to edit student details.

iam fetch values from database. blood group fetch from database to display select box. and also display other blood groups in same select box.

```
select class="form-control" name="studbldgrp" id="studbldgrp">
 option value="{{$student->studbldgrp}}">{{$student->studbldgrp}}</option>
        option value="O+ve">O+ve</option>
        option value="O-ve">O-ve</option>
        <option value="A+ve">A+ve</option>
        <option value="A-ve">A-ve</option>
        <option value="B+ve">B+ve</option>
        <option value="B-ve">B-ve</option>
        <option value="AB+ve">AB+ve</option>
        <option value="AB-ve">AB-ve</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
```

my problem is if im fetch value is A+ ,and display in select box. but it also in option value field.
 i no need to again this value(A+)A +ve  in select option field.

how to disable this field???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of your groups. Than iterate over it and don't print value matches $student->studbldgrp.
Array in php:

```
$groups = array(
'O+ve',
'O-ve',
'A+ve',
'A-ve',
'B+ve',
'B-ve',
'AB+ve',
'AB-ve',
'Other'
);
```

Blade template:

```
<select class="form-control" name="studbldgrp" id="studbldgrp">
    <option value="{{$student->studbldgrp}}">{{$student->studbldgrp}}</option>
    @foreach ($groups as $group)
        @if ($group != $struden->studbldgrp)
        <option value="{{ $group }}">{{ $group }}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</select>
```